# Same query showing different result when used as string in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, string

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT [ServerName]+ '\' + PARSENAME(REPLACE([Instance],'\','.'), 1) AS SIN,DATE FROM [DBReports].[dbo].[Accesslevelreport]
```

**C# query**

```
 "SELECT [ServerName]+ '\' + PARSENAME(REPLACE([Instance],'\','.'), 1) AS SIN,DATE FROM [DBReports].[dbo].[Accesslevelreport]";
```

I want to convert it in C# but results are different as compared to running in SQL

```
 Results from SQL=  ANDSQLP47\DWMOD  
  Results from C#= ANDSQLP47ANDSQLP47\DWMOD
```

**Expected Result**

```
Data in [ServerName]= ANDSQLP47
Data in [Instance] =ANDSQLP47\DWMOD
```

SIN column will contain the Server Name and Instance Name, separated with a backslash ('\'). If the 
instance field read from the database contains a slash in the text ('\'), remove 
the slash and everything to the left of it before combining the fields for the 
SIN column of the spreadsheet (only truncate this for processing - nothing 
changes in the database).
 **For example** : If the instance field contains 
'ANDSQLP47\CTOPROD8R2', then truncate that to 'CTOPROD8R2' before
combining it with the ServerName field.

Comment: it seems like your query has some escape characters. For example, if you want to add a backslash character to your string, you should use '\\', not '\' . Use double backslash instead of one backslash.

Comment: I have tried can you tell me the correct syntax ?

Comment: it can be like 
 SELECT [ServerName]+ '\\' + PARSENAME(REPLACE([Instance],'\\','.'), 1) AS SIN,DATE 
FROM [DBReports].[dbo].[Accesslevelreport];

Comment: You may *not* have to escape anything if you simply prepend your string literal with `@` but that depends on how you actually wrote the string in C#. What you posted may be the content of a string variable but it's *not* C# code. What is the actual code?

Answer (score 1):

Just escape your query.

```
var query = @"SELECT [ServerName]\PARSENAME(REPLACE([Instance],'\','.'), 1) AS SIN,DATE" + 
                                "FROM [DBReports].[dbo].[Accesslevelreport]";

or

var query = @"
      SELECT [ServerName]\PARSENAME(REPLACE([Instance],'\','.'), 1) AS SIN, DATE 
      FROM [DBReports].[dbo].[Accesslevelreport]
";
```

Comment: Hooray for verbatim strings :) They even remove the need for `" + "` at line breaks ;)

Comment: Yes in this case the + is not needed at all.